# How do I configure and reboot an HDInsight cluster running on Azure?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, configure, reboot, azure-hdinsight

Specifically, I want to change the maximum number of mappers and the maximum number of reducers for each node in an HDInsight cluster running on Microsoft Azure.

Using remote desktop, I logged in to the head node.  I edited the mapred-site.xml file on the head node and changed the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and the mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum values.  I tried rebooting the head node, but I was not able to reboot.  I used the start-onebox.cmd and stop-onebox.cmd scripts to try and start/stop HDInsight.

I then ran a streaming mapreduce passing the desired number of reducers to the hadoop-streaming.jar, but the number of reducers was still limited by the previous value of mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum.  Most of my reducers were pending execution.

Do I need to change the mapred-site.xml file on every node?  Is there an easy way to change this, or do I need to remote desktop into every node?  How do I reboot or restart the cluster so that my new values are used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a while since the question was posted, but I would like to post for other users who may find useful.

There are 2 ways you can change Hadoop configuration files (such as mapred-site.xml, hive-site.xml etc) on HDinsight

Option #1:
This is the easiest - you can supply the hadoop configuration values per job, as shown in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/02/13/how-to-pass-hadoop-configuration-values-for-a-job-via-hdinsight-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx)

Option #2:
You can customize HDinsight cluster with hadoop configuration values during provisioning or installing a cluster, as shown in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx)

Manually modifying a config file is not supported and the change will be lost when the Azure VM gets re-imaged.